# How can I export contents of an oracle table to a file?

Tags: oracle, export

Getting ready to clean up some old tables which are no longer in use, but I would like to be able to archive the contents before removing them from the database.

Is it possible to export the contents of a table to a file?  Ideally, one file per table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Oracle's export tool: [exp](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ)

Edit:

```
exp name/pwd@dbname file=filename.dmp tables=tablename rows=y indexes=n triggers=n grants=n
```

Comment: expdp (datapump export) is replacing exp.  It will be faster and offers more features, such as parallelism and compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using Python and cx_Oracle module.
Python script will extract data to disk in CSV format.

Here’s how you connect to Oracle using Python/cx_Oracle:

```
constr='scott/tiger@localhost:1521/ORCL12'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(constr)
cur = con.cursor()
```

After data fetch you can loop through Python list and save data in CSV format.

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(cur)):
    f_out.write('\n'.join([column_delimiter.join(row[0]) for row in chunk]))
    f_out.write('\n')
```

I used this approach when I wrote [TableHunter-For-Oracle](https://github.com/alexbuz/TableHunter-For-Oracle/tree/master/docs)

Comment: If CSV is the requirement, then you can just use the CSV markup in sqlplus.

Comment: true, but I had a script that creates one file per table. I thought it fits the bill.

Comment: I suspect a Python module using cursors and string concatenation functions is going to be _way_ slower than a native Oracle dump.