# Oracle Data Access for .NET

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an MVC3 ASP.NET web application that uses Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) x86 to connect to an Oracle database. The below code within my app will execute a query in an Oracle database table, and then write the query results to an output file using StreamWriter.

This below code reads about 12 thousand records per minute from an Oracle database table (even without using streamwriter to write to an output file).

I'm wondering if any of you know of a way to have improved performance to read more records per minute - perhaps another driver that you know of? Thanks, I really appreciate it!

```
        _dbCommand.CommandText = query;

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(output, append, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (var reader = _dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    var count = reader.FieldCount;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //get records
                        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            var txt = reader[i].ToString();

                            sw.Write(txt);
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine();

                    }
                }
            }
```

UPDATE:

It looks like the bottleneck is with ODP.NET. It takes 53 seconds to read/iterate over a "select top 10k" type query from any table in my Oracle database.

```
_dbCommand.CommandText = query;
using (var reader = _dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where's the field separator???. A quick win might be get sql to return one column e.g select A + '|' + B + '|' C as Line From MyTable, unless the lien length is huge.

Comment: But first you should see where the bottleneck is, database, network, or disk.

Comment: this might be of use as well. let the db do it's stuff and then just move the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021810/how-can-i-export-contents-of-an-oracle-table-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Tony! The bottleneck is with ODP.NET. It takes 53 seconds to read 10k records from any table in my Oracle DB. Executing a query within oracle itself takes nanoseconds, so i'm trying to figure out why ODP.NET slows the read process down. Any ideas? Do you know of another data access library to connect .NET app to Oracle DB that would be faster?

Comment: Now you isolated the issue, I'd say your best bet was a specific question in DBA.StackExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the most performance, then I suggest you skip the c# part completely.

1. run a explain plan on your query to tune its performance.
2. use Oracle UTL_FILE to write the data to a file.

**UPDATE**

First off, you still need to tune your SQL query to make your query run as fast as possible.

Then, the question is how to get the data to a file quickly. Your `sw.Write` will not be the fastest because it writes too little data too often.

Try setting its `AutoFlush` property to `false` and call `Flush` manually to write to disk.

You'll need to test different buffer size to find out which works the best.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, it looks like there's no way for us to skip the c# part since we need our web app to be able to filter the csv and know certain things about the location of the csv in order to handle other areas of the app. Do you happen to know of a way to increase performance, while still using the c# part?

Comment: Thanks, Ray! I experimented with using Flush to manually write to disk, and this seemed to help, however I see there's a bottleneck with ODP.NET. It takes 53 seconds to do a pure read (without writing or anything else) over 10k records from an Oracle DB table. Any ideas for other libraries or anything else?

Comment: All the libraries I have tried are Micrsoft Oracle Client, Oracle ODP.NET and Devart but I couldn't tell which one is faster. But I wouldn't expect a different library would provide much better performance if you haven't identify where the bottleneck is. Once again, SQL tuning, network latency, DB hardware and library all have impacts to performance but first, you need to identify where is the slowest.

Comment: Ok I found the culprit. The issue is that ODP.NET is really slow reading from this table when a specific column that is varchar2(4000 BYTE) is included in the select statement. Selecting every column except this one in this table takes only 4 seconds. Any idea how i can handle this column differently with ODP.NET?

Comment: Does the column need to be that big? If not, you may need to go back to re-size the column and make it smaller. Do you need all the data in that column? If not, you may `substr` it to just get the first x number of characters. If both questions are yes, I would re-model the data in that column with multiple tables. The bottom line is that if you have to move 1 ton of goods, you'll need x amount of force. In many cases, you'll found you don't need to move all of them at once. Do less with less will get you the top performance.