# How to replace a table in QA server with another table in production server?

Tags: oracle, toad

I want to take backup of a table from production server to QA server. The source table has around 7m data present in it..just, I need to take a copy of all 7m records to an existing table in QA..I am using toad version 11.0.0.116
how to do this? Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export contents of an oracle table to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021810/how-can-i-export-contents-of-an-oracle-table-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you're patient enough, just *copy* files from *source* to *target*. Here's how:

- a table must exist in both production and QA schema (I presume that the target should be empty)
- connect to both schemas
- in production server (surce), right-click that table name
- from the menu, choose "copy data to another schema"
- set destination connection & schema (that would be the QA schema, target)
- see whether you want to enable/disable some other parameters (checkboxes)
- run the copy process (there's a green triangle "Begin copying data" button at the top of the window

The copying process will start and, eventually, finish (successfully).

Otherwise, export/import is another, probably quicker option. I use it from operating system command prompt. It requires some additional steps (there must be a directory (Oracle object) you'd use to manipulate the DMP file), you have to follow the Data Pump export & import syntax, ...). Or, you could even use the *original* exp & imp utilities, which are a little bit simpler and work on the client.

Or, you could export current data into a CSV file and load it into the target schema using SQL*Loader. It requires you to know how to create a control file.

As you can see, there are quite a few options. Pick the one you find the most appropriate; some are simpler, another ones are quicker but more complex ...