# Optimize SQL file performance

Tags: html, sql, oracle, batch-file

I am generating back up of oracle table using batch file that invokes a .sql file using SQL PLUS but it is taking almost 90 minutes to generate a HTML back up with 90000+ records. Note that table is many columns.

Below is code for sql file. Please advise on how to reduce time as currently it takes 90 minutes. Also can we generate multiple files (Each file for each table) within same SQL ?

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON HEAD "<TITLE>MY TABLE</title> - <STYLE TYPE='TEXT/CSS'><!--BODY {background: ffffc6} --></STYLE>"
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SPOOL '\\PATH\OR\URL/my_table.htm';
select /*+parallel(a,8) full(a)*/ * from my_table a;
SPOOL OFF;
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
SET ECHO ON
EXIT
```

Comment: You may want to avoid using HTML markup; using HTML markup is going to increase the amount of data produced, and overhead for generating the HTML markup.  You can also try using `set termout off` before your `spool` command, to avoid echoing output to the terminal and that just sends the output of the query to the spool file.

Comment: Using `parallel` here is counterproductive, as you are spending much of your time in the fetching phase. Remove that as well as what @Mark Steward has said. Having said that, why are you using HTML to create a backup of a table ?? I am trying to imagine what is the reason for it, but I can't

Comment: You may also want to increase arraysize, e.g. set arraysize 500 before the spool

Comment: I removed the SET MARKUP HTML ON and SET MARKUP HTML OFF, Also removed parallel /*+parallel(a,8) full(a)*/ & tried SET TERMOUT OFF but now batch file does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export contents of an oracle table to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021810/how-can-i-export-contents-of-an-oracle-table-to-a-file). Use appropriate tools for data import/export instead of simple spooling (which has a lot of possibilities to fail)

Comment: How does this relate to tag [tag:batch-file]? You mention it in the description but you share no such code…

Comment: @aschipfl, I am using the batch file(.bat) to invoke .sql file. Below is the code for batch file.

echo start
cls
sqlplus username/password@databasename @URL\my_file.sql

PROMPT TABLES UPDATED
:END

Comment: @astentx, I don't have Python installed & little familiarity with it.

Comment: Alright then, please [edit] your post and include the code of the batch file; thank you!

Comment: There's nothing about python in this task, because data pump is the Oracle's supplied tool for the fastest way of data import and export. When you use HTML for data storage, the metadata (HTML tags) may take as much space as the data itself. And if you export the data not only for fun, I cannot imagine the following restore process: as far as I know Oracle uses DOM parser, not event-based stream processor. So you'll never restore the data from that HTML, whose DOM will take gigabytes in memory. Finally, spooling into flat file will fail in case of linebrakes. Being said, use appropriate tools

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding the purpose of creating a back up of a table using `html`, the only way to run as fast as possible would be something like this:

1. `termout` to off will avoid to echo the result
2. `parallel` removing the parallel hint will make the fetch faster, as this query is just fetching time. If you use parallel, you need to coordinate the QC with the slaves, which in this case is a waste of time.
3. Increasing `arraysize` allows SQL*Plus to return more rows in one fetch, thus lessening the required number of network round trips between it and the database server. The tradeoff is that larger array size settings require more memory. Take that in mind in order to use the better tradeoff ( default 15, limit 5000 )

Having explaining that, one option would be

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON HEAD "<TITLE>MY TABLE</title> - <STYLE TYPE='TEXT/CSS'><!--BODY {background: ffffc6} --></STYLE>"
SET ECHO OFF TERMOUT OFF ARRAYSIZE 5000 -- I put 5000 which is the maximum
SET PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL '\\PATH\OR\URL/my_table.htm';
select * from my_table a;
SPOOL OFF;
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
EXIT
```

Comment: I dont want to set PAGESIZE to 0 as it will remove headers

Comment: Also how to track progress now ?? as cmd screen only shows status "Connected to oracle database ----" and then -

Comment: Hi Roberto, Seems that file is getting generated but not able to track progress

Comment: @kiss.shoremishra Is there anything in v$session_longops while the query is running?

Comment: Sqlplus fast mode (since 12.2) will do the arraysize and a few other nice things for you. If you want to make spooling via sql*plus as fast as possible that is what you should be using now. For an actual table backup, this isn't a solution (I dread to think what the restore is going to look like).

Comment: @kiss.shoremishra , then remove the `set pagesize 0`. for extractions is normally used to avoid pagination in the output.